# Python: Take maximum values of two dataframes to create third dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Problem

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, 44, 1], 
                   "B":[5, 2, 54, 3, 2] }) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[20, 16, 7, 3, 8], 
                   "B":[14, 3, 17, 2, 6]})
```

Given two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, I want to create a third dataframe, `df3` which contains the maximum values of the two dataframes.

```py
df3 =pd.DataFrame({"A":[20, 16, 7, 44, 8], 
                   "B":[14, 3, 54, 3, 6]})
```

### Attempt

I created two temp dataframes with both columns of A from `df1` and `df2` into a `numpy` array, then found each maximum value. The same process was repeated for B. I then combined both arrays for A and B to get `df3`. However, I feel this is not elegant and I want a more efficient method for accomplishing this task.

Thank you @beny @Romero_91 @cameron-riddell ... your solutions are very elegant and simpler than mine!
I knew I was missing something!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the dataframe method `combine` to perform an elementwise maximum:

```
import numpy as np

df3 = df1.combine(df2, np.maximum)
print(df3)
    A   B
0  20  14
1  16   3
2   7  54
3  44   3
4   8   6
```

As pointed out by @anky, `np.maximum` on its own performs this elemnt-wise comparison. It's always good to remember those pure numpy solutions especially when they lead to such clean & simple code.

```
df3 = np.maximum(df1, df2)
print(df3)
    A   B
0  20  14
1  16   3
2   7  54
3  44   3
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do

```
out = df2.mask(df1>df2,df1)
Out[141]: 
    A   B
0  20  14
1  16   3
2   7  54
3  44   3
4   8   6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `where` method of `numpy` as:

```
import numpy as np

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1>df2, df1, df2), columns=['A', 'B'])
```